# Custom Paging in ASP.Net Web Application

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server

I have following code for doing custom paging from an asp.net web application.

**Points of interest**

1. It uses Link Buttons  as suggested in
   https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14335067/passing-search-parameters-to-same-page-when-hyperlink-clicked
2. The link buttons are added in Page_Load itself as listed in
   https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14364332/dynamic-controls-event-handlers-working
3. It is made as user control for reuse

**QUESTIONS**

1. Is there any pitfalls in this approach?
2. Is there any improvement suggestions?

**User Control Markup**

```
<%@ Control Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="PagingUserControl.ascx.cs"
Inherits="PagingTestWebApplication.PagingUserControl" %>
<div class="pagingSection" id="pagingSection" runat="server">
<asp:LinkButton ID="lnkPrevious" runat="server" CssClass='page-numbers prev' Visible="false" OnClick="LinkButton_Click">Prev</asp:LinkButton>
<asp:LinkButton ID="lnkFirst" runat="server" CssClass='page-numbers' Visible="false"
    OnClick="LinkButton_Click">1</asp:LinkButton>
<asp:Label runat="server" ID="lblFirstDots" CssClass="page-numbers prev" Visible="false"
    Text="..."></asp:Label>
<asp:PlaceHolder ID="plhDynamicLink" runat="server"></asp:PlaceHolder>
<asp:Label runat="server" ID="lblSecondDots" Visible="false" CssClass="page-numbers prev"
    Text="..."></asp:Label>
<asp:LinkButton ID="lnkLast" runat="server" CssClass='page-numbers' Visible="false"
    OnClick="LinkButton_Click">Last</asp:LinkButton>
<asp:LinkButton ID="lnkNext" runat="server" CssClass='page-numbers next' Visible="false" OnClick="LinkButton_Click">Next</asp:LinkButton>
 </div>
```

**User Control Code Behind**

```
public partial class PagingUserControl : System.Web.UI.UserControl
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    public int PreviousIndex { get; set; }
    public int CurrentClickedIndex { get; set; }

    public event EventHandler PaginationLinkClicked;

    protected void LinkButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //Assumption: Text of the LinkButton will be same as index
        LinkButton clickedLinkButton = (LinkButton)sender;

        if (String.Equals(clickedLinkButton.Text, "Next"))
        {
            //Next Page index will be one greater than current
            //Note: If the current index is the last page, "Next" control will be in disabled state
            CurrentClickedIndex = PreviousIndex + 1;
        }
        else if (String.Equals(clickedLinkButton.Text, "Prev"))
        {
            //Previous Page index will be one less than current
            //Note: If the current index is the first page, "Prev" control will be in disabled state
            CurrentClickedIndex = PreviousIndex - 1;
        }
        else
        {
            CurrentClickedIndex = Convert.ToInt32(clickedLinkButton.Text, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
        }

        //Raise event
        if (this.PaginationLinkClicked != null)
        {
            this.PaginationLinkClicked(clickedLinkButton, e);
        }

    }

    public void PreAddAllLinks(int tableDataCount,int pageSize,  int currentIndex)
    {
        if (tableDataCount > 0)
        {
            PagingInfo info = PagingHelper.GetAllLinks(tableDataCount, pageSize, currentIndex);

            //Remove all controls from the placeholder
            plhDynamicLink.Controls.Clear();

            if (info.PaginationLinks != null)
            {
                foreach (LinkButton link in info.PaginationLinks)
                {
                    //Adding Event handler must be done inside Page_Laod /Page_Init
                    link.Click += new EventHandler(LinkButton_Click);

                    //Validation controls should be executed before link click.
                    link.ValidationGroup = "Search";
                    this.plhDynamicLink.Controls.Add(link);
                }
            }

        }
    }

    public void AddPageLinks(int tableDataCount, int pageSize, int index)
    {

        if (tableDataCount > 0)
        {
            pagingSection.Visible = true;
            PagingInfo info = PagingHelper.GetPageLinks(tableDataCount, pageSize, index);

            //Remove all controls from the placeholder
            plhDynamicLink.Controls.Clear();

            if (info.PaginationLinks != null)
            {
                lnkPrevious.Visible = info.PaginationLinks.Count > 0 ? true : false;
                lnkNext.Visible = info.PaginationLinks.Count > 0 ? true : false;

                foreach (LinkButton link in info.PaginationLinks)
                {
                    //Validation controls should be executed before link click.
                    link.ValidationGroup = "Search";
                    this.plhDynamicLink.Controls.Add(link);
                }
            }


            //Dots visiblity
            if (info.IsEndDotsVisible != null)
            {
                lblSecondDots.Visible = Convert.ToBoolean(info.IsEndDotsVisible, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
            }
            else
            {
                lblSecondDots.Visible = false;
            }

            if (info.IsStartDotsVisible != null)
            {
                lblFirstDots.Visible = Convert.ToBoolean(info.IsStartDotsVisible, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
            }
            else
            {
                lblFirstDots.Visible = false;
            }

            //First and Last Links
            if (info.IsFirstLinkVisible != null)
            {
                lnkFirst.Visible = Convert.ToBoolean(info.IsFirstLinkVisible, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
            }
            else
            {
                lnkFirst.Visible = false;
            }

            if (info.IsLastLinkVisible != null)
            {
                lnkLast.Visible = Convert.ToBoolean(info.IsLastLinkVisible, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
                lnkLast.Text = info.NumberOfPagesRequired.ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
            }
            else
            {
                lnkLast.Visible = false;
            }


            //For first page, there is no previous
            if (index != 1 && info.NumberOfPagesRequired != 1)
            {
                lnkPrevious.Enabled = true;
            }
            else
            {
                lnkPrevious.Enabled = false;
            }


            //For last page there is no Next
            if (index != info.NumberOfPagesRequired && info.NumberOfPagesRequired != 1)
            {
                lnkNext.Enabled = true;
            }
            else
            {
                lnkNext.Enabled = false;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            pagingSection.Visible = false;
        }

    }

 }
```

DTO

```
public class PagingInfo
{
    public Collection<LinkButton> PaginationLinks { get; set; }
    public bool? IsEndDotsVisible { get; set; }
    public bool? IsStartDotsVisible { get; set; }
    public bool? IsFirstLinkVisible { get; set; }
    public bool? IsLastLinkVisible { get; set; }
    public int NumberOfPagesRequired { get; set; }

}
```

Helper

```
public static class PagingHelper
{
    public static PagingInfo GetAllLinks(int totalRecordsInTable, int pageSize, int previousIndex)
    {

        string LinkButtonIDPrefix = "lnK";
        PagingInfo pagingInfo = new PagingInfo();
        pagingInfo.PaginationLinks = new Collection<LinkButton>();

        if (totalRecordsInTable > 0)
        {
            int itemsBeforePage = 4;
            int itemsAfterPage = 2;
            int dynamicDisplayCount = itemsBeforePage + 1 + itemsAfterPage;

            Double numberOfPagesRequired = Convert.ToDouble(totalRecordsInTable / pageSize);
            if (totalRecordsInTable % pageSize != 0)
            {
                numberOfPagesRequired = numberOfPagesRequired + 1;
            }

            if (numberOfPagesRequired == 0)
            {
                numberOfPagesRequired = 1;
            }


            //Note: This function adds only the probable Links that the user can click (based on previous click).
            //This is needed sice dynamic controls need to be added while Page_Load itself for event handlers to work
            //In case of any bug, easiest way is add all links from 1 to numberOfPagesRequired
            //Following is an optimized way

            int endOfLeftPart = dynamicDisplayCount;
            //User may click "1". So the first 7 items may be required for display. Hence add them for event handler purpose
            for (int i = 1; i <= endOfLeftPart; i++)
            {
                //Create dynamic Links 
                LinkButton lnk = new LinkButton();
                lnk.ID = LinkButtonIDPrefix + i.ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
                lnk.Text = i.ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
                pagingInfo.PaginationLinks.Add(lnk);
            }


            int startOfRighPart = Convert.ToInt32(numberOfPagesRequired) - dynamicDisplayCount + 1;

            //User may click the last link. So the last 7 items may be required for display. Hence add them for event handler purpose
            for (int i = startOfRighPart; i <= Convert.ToInt32(numberOfPagesRequired); i++)
            {
                //Links already added should not be added again
                if (i > endOfLeftPart)
                {
                    //Create dynamic Links 
                    LinkButton lnk = new LinkButton();
                    lnk.ID = LinkButtonIDPrefix + i.ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
                    lnk.Text = i.ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
                    pagingInfo.PaginationLinks.Add(lnk);
                }
            }

            //User may click on 4 items before current index as well as 2 items after current index
            for (int i = (previousIndex - itemsBeforePage); i <= (previousIndex + itemsAfterPage); i++)
            {
                //Links already added should not be added again
                if (i > endOfLeftPart && i < startOfRighPart)
                {
                    //Create dynamic Links 
                    LinkButton lnk = new LinkButton();
                    lnk.ID = LinkButtonIDPrefix + i.ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
                    lnk.Text = i.ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
                    pagingInfo.PaginationLinks.Add(lnk);
                }
            }



        }
        return pagingInfo;
    }
    public static PagingInfo GetPageLinks(int totalRecordsInTable, int pageSize, int currentIndex)
    {
        string LinkButtonIDPrefix = "lnK";
        PagingInfo pagingInfo = new PagingInfo();
        pagingInfo.PaginationLinks = new Collection<LinkButton>();

        if (totalRecordsInTable > 0)
        {

            int itemsBeforePage = 4;
            int itemsAfterPage = 2;
            int dynamicDisplayCount = itemsBeforePage + 1 + itemsAfterPage;

            Double numberOfPagesRequired = Convert.ToDouble(totalRecordsInTable / pageSize);
            if (totalRecordsInTable % pageSize != 0)
            {
                numberOfPagesRequired = numberOfPagesRequired + 1;
            }

            if (numberOfPagesRequired == 0)
            {
                numberOfPagesRequired = 1;
            }

            //Generate dynamic paging 
            int start;
            if (currentIndex <= (itemsBeforePage + 1))
            {
                start = 1;
            }
            else
            {
                start = currentIndex - itemsBeforePage;
            }

            int lastAddedLinkIndex = 0;
            int? firtsAddedLinkIndex = null;

            for (int i = start; i < start + dynamicDisplayCount; i++)
            {

                if (i > numberOfPagesRequired)
                {
                    break;
                }

                //Create dynamic Links 
                LinkButton lnk = new LinkButton();
                lnk.ID = LinkButtonIDPrefix + i.ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
                lnk.Text = i.ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
                lastAddedLinkIndex = i;

                if (firtsAddedLinkIndex == null)
                {
                    firtsAddedLinkIndex = i;
                }


                //Check whetehr current page
                if (i == currentIndex)
                {
                    lnk.CssClass = "page-numbers current";
                }
                else
                {
                    lnk.CssClass = "page-numbers";
                }

                pagingInfo.PaginationLinks.Add(lnk);
            }

            if (numberOfPagesRequired > dynamicDisplayCount)
            {
                //Set dots (ellipse) visibility
                pagingInfo.IsEndDotsVisible = lastAddedLinkIndex == numberOfPagesRequired ? false : true;
                pagingInfo.IsStartDotsVisible = firtsAddedLinkIndex <= 2 ? false : true;

                //First and Last Page Links
                pagingInfo.IsLastLinkVisible = lastAddedLinkIndex == numberOfPagesRequired ? false : true;
                pagingInfo.IsFirstLinkVisible = firtsAddedLinkIndex == 1 ? false : true;

            }

            pagingInfo.NumberOfPagesRequired = Convert.ToInt32(numberOfPagesRequired);

        }
        return pagingInfo;

    }
 }
```

**ASPX Page**

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="LijosTest.aspx.cs" Inherits="PagingTestWebApplication.LijosTest" %>

<%@ Register TagPrefix="CP" TagName="LijosPager" Src="~/PagingUserControl.ascx" %>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">

 <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
 <head runat="server">
 <title></title>
 <style type="text/css">
    .page-numbers
    {
        border: 1px solid #CCC;
        color: #808185;
        display: block;
        float: left;
        font-size: 9pt;
        margin-right: 3px;
        padding: 4px 4px 3px;
        text-decoration: none;
    }

    .page-numbers.current
    {
        background-color: #808185;
        border: 1px solid #808185;
        color: white;
        font-weight: bold;
    }

    .page-numbers.next, .page-numbers.prev
    {
        border: 1px solid white;
        font-size: 12pt;
    }
 </style>
 </head>
 <body>
 <form id="form1" runat="server">
 <asp:TextBox ID="txtEmpName" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
 <asp:Button ID="btnSearch" runat="server" Text="Button" ValidationGroup="Search"
    OnClick="btnSearch_Click" />
 <div>
    <asp:GridView ID="grdEmployee" runat="server">
    </asp:GridView>
 </div>
 <CP:LijosPager ID="uclPager" runat="server" />
 <asp:HiddenField ID="hdnCurrentIndex" runat="server" Value="Blank Value" />
 </form>
 </body>
 </html>
```

**ASPX Code Behind**

```
public partial class LijosTest : System.Web.UI.Page
{

    private int pageSize = 25;
    private int pageIndex = 1;

    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //Register event handler for user control event
        this.uclPager.PaginationLinkClicked += new EventHandler(paginationLink_Click);

        if (Page.IsPostBack)
        {
            //During all postbacks - Add the pagination links to the page
            int tableDataCount = DatabaseSimulator.GetEmployeesCount(txtEmpName.Text);

            string defaultInitialValueForHiddenControl = "Blank Value";
            int indexFromPreviousDataRetrieval = 1;
            if (!String.Equals(hdnCurrentIndex.Value, defaultInitialValueForHiddenControl))
            {
                indexFromPreviousDataRetrieval = Convert.ToInt32(hdnCurrentIndex.Value, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
            }

            //Set property of user control
            uclPager.PreviousIndex = indexFromPreviousDataRetrieval;

            //Call method in user control
            uclPager.PreAddAllLinks(tableDataCount, pageSize, indexFromPreviousDataRetrieval);
        }

    }

    protected void btnSearch_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //When Search is clicked, reset the index to 1 (first page)
        pageIndex = 1;
        BindBusinessProcessActivitiesData();
    }

    protected void paginationLink_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //When link is clicked, set the pageIndex from user control property
        pageIndex = uclPager.CurrentClickedIndex;
        BindBusinessProcessActivitiesData();
    }

    private void BindBusinessProcessActivitiesData()
    {

        string name = txtEmpName.Text; 
        List<Employee> searchResult = DatabaseSimulator.GetData(name, pageSize, pageIndex).ToList();

        grdEmployee.DataSource = searchResult;
        grdEmployee.DataBind();

        //Index
        hdnCurrentIndex.Value = pageIndex.ToString(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);

        //Get total number of records
        int tableDataCount = DatabaseSimulator.GetEmployeesCount(name);

        uclPager.AddPageLinks(tableDataCount, pageSize, pageIndex);

    }


}
```

Database Part

```
public static class DatabaseSimulator
{

    public static IEnumerable<Employee> GetData(string name, int pageSize,int index)
    {
        IEnumerable<Employee> employeesSource = SearchEmployees(name);
        int skipUpto = ((index-1) * pageSize);

        IEnumerable<Employee> searchResult = employeesSource.Skip(skipUpto).Take(pageSize);
        return searchResult;

    }

    public static int GetEmployeesCount(string name)
    {
        List<Employee> employees = GetEmployees();
        int employeesCount = 0;

        if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(name))
        {
            employeesCount = employees.Count;
        }
        else
        {
            List<Employee> selectedEmployees = employees.Where(r => r.Name == name).ToList();
            employeesCount =  selectedEmployees.Count;
        }

        return employeesCount;
    }

    private static IEnumerable<Employee> SearchEmployees(string name)
    {
        List<Employee> employees = GetEmployees();
        if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(name))
        {
            return employees;
        }

        return employees.Where(r => r.Name == name);
    }

    private static List<Employee> GetEmployees()
    {
        List<Employee> employees = new List<Employee>();

        for (int i = 1; i <= 400; i++)
        {
            Employee emp = new Employee();
            emp.EmpID = i;
            if (i % 2 == 0)
            {
                emp.Name = "Divisible by 2";
            }
            else if  (i % 3 == 0)
            {
                emp.Name = "Divisible by 3";
            }
            else if (i % 5 == 0)
            {
                emp.Name = "Divisible by 5";
            }
            else if (i % 7 == 0)
            {
                emp.Name = "Divisible by 7";
            }
            else 
            {
                emp.Name = "Other -- "+ i.ToString();
            }

            employees.Add(emp);
        }

        return employees;
    }

}

public class Employee
{
    public int EmpID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: @Knownasilya. Thanks. I have accepted possible answers. 75% acceptance now

Answer (score 1):

I have come across a scenario that will fail: Suppose there is an image button control in the same page along with our button. Our code for pre-adding links will be called in all postbacks.

Assume that the value in textbox is supposed to be an integer. We have added a validation that will fire when button is clicked. But when image button is clicked this validation should not be fired [The image button is redirecting to another page. Hence no validation should be there].

In the above scenario, when image button is clicked (with a non-integer value in textbox), a postback will happen and it will cause an exception.

To handle this scnario, we need to know the `control's ID that caused the postback`. I hope the answer in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3175513/on-postback-how-can-i-check-which-control-cause-postback-in-page-init-event will be helpful for this purpose.